I'd like to make my cat try his cat puzzle
I have a difficult cat. (To some people, that kind of pet is known as "a cat.") He's always complaining, but I'm never sure what complaints are about. In some cases, it's clear he wants to play, but as soon as I get up, he hides. When he comes back, he gets bored by the wand toy after about ten seconds, but wants to play again as soon as I put it down. In other words: a cat.
He used to be very fat, and when I tried to put him on a diet, he would just scream for food all day. He now has an automatic feeder, and he knows that meowing won't have any influence on the feeder, so he's given up on that. But he's always hungry. I don't enjoy this, but being overweight is one of the main causes of health problems for cats. So I got him a cat puzzle. It's the "interactive tube" type. The kind with treats hidden in tubes that the cat can tip. (While looking for the name, this puzzle came up as "advanced," to my surprise.)
When he was a kitten and I got a new bag of cat food, he would try to tear the package open to get to the food inside. Now that he's 12, I can leave the top of the feeder open and he won't look inside. I guess he's too old to be that curious. The tubes currently have no cover at all. (You can adjust the difficulty of the puzzle by adding various covers to the tubes.) If you tip them just over horizontal position, all the food falls out. If I tip a tube that way to show him: 1) he does not care and 2) as soon as the food has fallen out, he rushes to get it.
I think he'd really love that game if he just tried it. But I don't know how to communicate that to him. While writing this, I also got him an easier puzzle online.
Still, is there anything I can do to get him to actually try the tipping tube puzzle?
Thanks!

I assume that the toy is one of this kind (random example found on amazon):

I do agree that this type of puzzle is quite advanced and hard to learn for pets. It took our dog several days to just understand the concept and then some more weeks to become familiar with the puzzle. To this day she mostly ignores it because it's much harder than other food puzzles.
Step one: lower your expectations
At 12 years, your cat may not be interested in such toys at all. It may be too physically demanding to lift his paws and flip the tubes. Ultimately you can never force him to have fun.
Step two: make it too easy
Right now your cat is learning: when you interact with this toy, some treats fall out. But what you really want is: when your cat interacts with this toy, some treats fall out.
If possible, adapt the toy in a way that it's so unstable that the treats fall out when your cat just randomly touches it. This is typically done by fastening the rod lower on the tube. If the difficulty of the toy cannot be adapted (because most manufacturers don't care to include this feature), carefully drill new holes in one of the tubes, slightly below the middle point.

If you can adapt the height of the entire toy, make it smaller and thereby easier for your can to investigate and use.
Use small treats that have a strong smell to incentivise your cat and use only one treat at a time. Play this "too easy" game for several days until you have the feeling that your cat likes the game and knows exactly what to do.
Step three: increase difficulty
Very slowly increase the difficulty by fastening the horizontal rod higher on the tube, as shown in the image above. Start with a configuration that doesn't topple over immediately, but also doesn't revert back to vertical immediately. By this point your cat will know that there are treats to get out, but he may not understand what needs to be done to get the treats out. This step took quite long for our dog, so I suggest you play with your cat on this difficulty for several days until it also gets "too easy" for him.
Step four: challenge!
If your cat likes the toy and understands how it works, you can slowly increase the difficulty further and further. Either fasten the vertical rod higher on the tubes or increase the height of the toy.
At a certain point the toy may get too challenging and your cat may no longer have fun using it. Our dog doesn't like the highest difficulty, but enthusiastically interacts with it on the second-to-highest level. If the effort becomes higher than the reward, you toy won't be used anymore.

Thank you so much! I already put it on the easiest setting. My cat seems to be full of energy when he wants to. (It is a he. Fixed, but still a he.) His easier puzzle had arrived. I'll start with that. Maybe he'll figure out the concept of puzzles through it.

You may want to try a different puzzle. My cats liked one that had covers which they had to slide or rotate to get to each treat. That's a much more natural action for a cat then flipping a tube against its weight, and so much easier to learn.
We generally don't do recommendations here, so I'm going to say talk to friends who have cats and ask them what kinds of food puzzles their cats have been successful with.
But remember that cats are very individualistic, and their degree of response to food as a motivation varies from cat to cat and from moment to moment. It always requires experimentation to find a toy that a cat will enjoy playing with, or at the very least past experimentation so you know what your cat's general preferences are. Just because a manufacturer labels something a cat toy does not mean it is something your cat will want to play with.
